# kotlin - required context, found AnkoAsyncContext

Tags: kotlin

> **SOLVED**

I'm trying to use `this` inside `doAsync` from `org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.8` but it's not letting me.

Snippet of my code:

```kotlin
doAsync {
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener {
        if (editTextInput.text.isEmpty()) {
            val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            alert.setTitle("You forgot something")
            alert.setMessage("Answer cannot be empty!")
            alert.show()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Use `this@YourActivityClassName` instead of `this`.

Comment: Tried using `this@CalculationActivity` but got the error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String`

Comment: That would have nothing to do with the code you've shown above.

Comment: My bad I was forgetting something, thanks!